# MYSQL 8.0.19 (ON PREMISE) as source in AWS DMS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-dms

Can someone please confirm if my on premise MYSQL 8.0.19 instance can be used as source in Aws Database migration service ,with target as aws redshift.
The articles I read show only MySQL versions 5.5, 5.6, and 5.7 as supported.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.html

Wondering if support is provided as of MAY 2020.

PS: I ran into problem while setting task (AWS DMS FULL load) with mysql(on premise) 8.0.19 as source and redshift as target.
The task is set but the table load fails with table error.

Answer (score 0):

AWS DMS frustratingly still doesn't support MySQL 8 as a source as far as I know.

Here's a related support thread in the AWS Developer Forums:
[DMS task fails when migrating RDS MySQL 8 database](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=927588&#927588) . In that thread, an AWS staffer commented on January 28 that it should be supported with DMS version 3.4 (the [current version is 3.3.2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_ReleaseNotes.html)), however they haven't provided any details on when we can expect 3.4 to be available.

Comment: But one of my colleague was successfull in getting RDS mysql 8+ migrated using DMS.My On the other hand is onprem mysql and I am failing with DMS. Finally used aws datapipeline  (I sync the table fully ,daily)